# What parts of Wild Shape are affected by the Shaping Focus feat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wild-shape

[Shaping Focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/shaping-focus):

> If you are a multiclassed druid, your wild shape ability is calculated as though your druid level were four higher, to a maximum level equal to your character level.

Does this feat affect every aspect Wild Shape, such as

- uses per day,
- duration,
- forms allowed (i.e. as beast shape I/II/II, elemental body I, etc.)?

Two examples:

**Tygal: Human Normal Druid 4/Fighter 4**

1. Has effective character level 8
2. Shaping Focus feat enables him to count his wildshape ability as he was a druid at 8th level (Normal Druid 4 plus 4 up to maximum his character level)
3. Can wildshape to medium elemental as per elemental body II
4. Can wildshape 3/day
5. Efect lasts 8 hrs or until he changes back

**Nazghymbatulu: Halfling Saurian Druid 4/Fighter 4**

1. Has effective character level 8
2. Shaping Focus feat enables him to count his wildshape ability as he was a druid at 8th level (Saurian Druid 4 plus 4 up to maximum his character level)
3. He can wildshape to medium air elemental or is he limited to small air elemental (Saurian Druid level -2) ...
4. He cant use wildshape ...
5. Can wildshape x/day
6. Efect lasts x hrs or until he changes back

Comment: I made major changes to your question to make it more readable. That said, your second example looks incomplete, which might just serve to highlight where you actually got really confused (which is good because it helps answerers).

Answer (score 5):

In the examples, Tygal's correctly using the feat Shaping Focus, but Nazghymbatulu isn't because the saurian shaman druid archetype delays Naz's wild shape ability until he's at least a Drd6.

#### A druid with the special ability wild shape who takes the feat [Shaping Focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/shaping-focus) increases his effective druid level by up to 4 for the special ability [wild shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid#TOC-Wild-Shape-Su-) but not beyond the creature's total character level

Thus a typical Drd4/Ftr3 who takes the feat [Shaping Focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/shaping-focus) employs the special ability wild shape a if the Drd4/Ftr3 were a Drd7. (I chose the Drd4/Ftr3 instead of Drd4/Ftr4 because in typical campaigns the latter character wouldn't have a feat available at that precise total character level.)

However, the feat Shaping Focus *can't* benefit the [saurian shaman](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo---druid-archetypes/saurian-shaman) Drd4/Ftr3 who, because of his archetype, until he reaches level 6 as a druid, lacks the special ability wild shape:

> At 6th level, a saurian shaman’s wild shape ability functions at her druid level –2. If she takes on the form of a reptile or a dinosaur, she instead uses her druid level +2.

Prior to 6th level, then, a saurian shaman *doesn't have* the special ability wild shape. Therefore a saurian shaman Drd4/Ftr3 is unable to meet the prerequisites of the feat Shaping Focus and can't get the feat's benefits were he able to somehow.

Likewise a creature with *no* druid levels that somehow managed to take the feat doesn't gain the special ability wild shape as if the creature were a level 4 druid.

By analogy, the feat is like a coupon for extra 4 toppings on a pizza; one must still *buy* a pizza to get the extra toppings.

Answer (score 0):

Wild shape RAW and RAI both seem to indicate you gain more uses per day out of shaping focus as well as increased power of wild shapes.

However, RAW, animals shamans *do* have the ability to wild shape at level 4. The ability simply says how wild shape functions once the shaman reaches level 6. I realize that this creates the bizarre situation that a shaman's off-spec wildshapes are better at level 5 than they are at 6, but that's correct by RAW.

cheers!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. The author disagrees with that reading [here](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l5il?APG-Druid-Shaman-Wildshaping-Modifiers-What#2), but it's valuable sometimes to make the case that the text doesn't match the author's intentions. Thank you for participating and have fun.